# MPI_Bcast 2D array

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm working on a MPI program with processes 2d array. At first I am broadcasting array with  ranges of rows which each rank should process - it works fine. Then I'm trying to broadcast 2d array `nextData` with is filled from array `data` in rank 0. It seems data is not broadcasted and program exits with code 0xc0000005 (Access Violation). What am I doing wrong?

Arrays `nextData` and `data` are members of MPIDataProcessor which instance is created in Main function. Both of them are initialized with function `tableAlloc` and `data` is filled with data only in root rank.

```
void MPIDataProcessor::shareData() {
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int* rowsPerRank = new int[size];
    int* rowsFromPerRank = new int[size];

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        int rem = dataSize % size;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            rowsPerRank[i] = dataSize / size;
            if (rem > 0) {
                rowsPerRank[i]++;
                rem--;
            }

            rowsFromPerRank[i] = sum;
            sum += rowsPerRank[i];
        }
    }
    
    MPI_Bcast(&dataSize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(rowsPerRank, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(rowsFromPerRank, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Each rank print which range of rows it processes - working ok
    cout << "Rank: " << rank << ". Counting rows: " << rowsFromPerRank[rank] << " - " << rowsFromPerRank[rank] + rowsPerRank[rank] - 1 << endl;

    nextData = tableAlloc(dataSize);
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < dataSize; j++)
                nextData[i][j] = data[i][j];
    }
    
    MPI_Bcast(&(nextData[0][0]), dataSize * dataSize, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Just to check if other ranks than 0 has data - here the failure occurs
    if (rank != 0)
    {
        cout << "Rank: " << rank <<endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
            cout << setw(3) << i << " -> ";
            for (int j = 0; j < dataSize; j++)
                cout << " " << showpoint << setw(4) << setprecision(3)
                << nextData[i][j];
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "END" << endl;
    }
}
```

tableAlloc function:

```
double **tableAlloc( int size ) {
    double **result;
    result = new double* [ size ]; // size rows
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        result[ i ] = new double[ size ]; // size cols
    return result;
}
```

EDIT

I've made some research and changed the matrix initialization function to make the allocation contiguous. Now the loop prints out the `nextData` matrix correctly but program just after crashes just after and doesn't reach that "END" print.

```
double** contiguousTableAlloc(int size) {
    double** result;
    result = new double* [size];
    result[0] = new double[size * size];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        result[i] = result[i - 1] + size;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This looks very much like a question I saw a few days ago. Are you reposting this?

Comment: You need to allocate data contiguously, not as a row of pointers to separate row blocks. Right now you're a `double**` which is not a pointer to data: it's a pointer to pointers. Whatever you're sending should be of type `double*`.

Comment: Trying to figure it out step by step. I've just fixed that allocation just before I saw your comment. Any ideas why is it still crashing?

Comment: Your code still shows a `double**` so I'm not sure what you fixed. Your allocation routine should have exactly *one* `new`.  And since you flagged this "c++" you shouldn't be using `new` at all. Use `std::vector` to allocate your data, and use `.data()` to get the send/recv buffer.

Comment: Well it's my university task and I cannot use vector and change nextData type. It has to be of type **double.

Comment: In that case your matrix is not contiguous and you can not send it in one go: you need to do one send per row, or use `MPI_Type_hindexed` which is very much not beginner stuff. And take it from me that this is bad design.